# Sys.time() and format() showing different results on desktop and docker image in R

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I am running a piece of code.

```
Sys.time()
format(Sys.time(), "%X")
```

When I run the code on my windows machine inside RStudio and through command prompt I get the time 24 hours and while using format I get in 12 hour which I expect.

But when deployed in Kubernetes, running the same commands gives my result in 24 hour format.

I am not able to get the reason behind it, or how I can correct my code so that it works properly.

**Desktop Version:**

[image]

**Docker Version:**

[image]

Comment: Since `"%X"` is documented as *"Locale-specific on output"*, what are the locale settings for your different R sessions? Run `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")` to see.

Comment: The output of `%X` formatting is locale specific, try using `%r` or `%I:%M %p`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the inputs. I will try them.

Comment: Docker is probably showing UTC time. As any good server should.

Comment: Actually it obviously is as it is printing "UTC" out (noticed after I posted).